Can a task executed by C++ std::async(std::launch::async...) be switched/stolen between threads?
In C++ on Windows, given a task started by std::async(std::launch::async, ...), can it be executed first by one thread, and after a possible context switch, stolen and executed by another thread?
For example, if inside of my task I create some thread_local variables, will they be preserved?
This doubt was motivated by a comment of my coworker, who read this paragraph

Just because it is called std::async does not mean it has anything to do with the async/await mechanisms in C#. Once a thread starts executing an async task it stays there.

std::async does not say anything about threads. It could execute the code in any kind of cooperative implementation. The link you provide is about .Net and totally unrelated. What is true, is that on windows, windows does use a threadpool (and a strange one at that, at a large number of threads it starts stalling and running into issues).  So you might be better of using std::thread + lambda + packaged_task and/or std::promise (so you have epxlicit control over what runs where)

If you're using std::async, you don't intend to directly get involved with threads; then why would you use thread_local objects? If it is hidden down a library, then that library must provide threading API and/or documentation about correct usage.

There is absolutely no way in C++ for anything to jump between threads.

@PepijnKramer "std::async does not say anything about threads" That's not true. https://eel.is/c++draft/futures.async#3.1 If launch​::​async is set in policy, calls invoke(auto(std​::​forward(f)), auto(std​::​forward(args))...) ([func.invoke], [thread.thread.constr]) as if in a new thread of execution represented by a thread object with the values produced by auto being materialized ([conv.rval]) in the thread that called async

You are right it says something about thread. For me it is the bit "as if in a new thread" that leaves a bit of room for the actual implementation (I think there are some possibilities to implement it using interrupts on machines that do not actively support threading). gcc/clang really use std::thread, msvc actually uses an (exhaustive) threadpool.

No.
Context switches move threads between cores. C++ thread_local objects move with the thread.
You do not know which thread will be used for std::async, or which thread_local objects already exist in that thread. That's abstracted away. (And one of the reasons I think std::async is not very useful - it has no concrete, reliable benefits but does have concrete limitations. It's similar to std::stack in that sense.)
